# char pointers, char arrays, and strings in the context of a function call

Tags: c++, string, arrays, char-pointer

What is the difference between the line that does not compile and the line that does compile?
The line that does not compile gives this warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'

Also, I'm aware casting (char *) on the string being passed in to the function would solve the problem, but I would like to understand why that's even necessary when the 2nd line compiles just fine.

```
class Student {

  public:

    Student( char name[] ) {

    }

}

int main() {

  Student stud( "Kacy" ); //does not compile
  char name[20] = "Kacy";   //compiles just fine

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `char[]` signature in the parameter is exactly the same as `char*`. In C++, it is illegal to convert a string constant `char const*` (the string `"Kacy"`) to a `char*` because strings are immutable.

Your second example compiles because the `name` is an actual array. There is no change to `char*`.

As a solution, change your parameter to take a const string array:

```
Student(char const name[]);
```

which again is the same as

```
String(char const *name);
```

though you're better off using `std::string`:

```
#include <string>

class String
{
    public:
        String(std::string name);
};
```

Comment: 'implicitly converted' is a bit inaccurate, IMHO.  There's no conversion, they're literally the same.  `char name[]` is just syntactic sugar for `char *name`.

Comment: @CarlNorum Yeah, you're right. Twas thinking of something else.

Comment: No problem, just wanted to clarify.

Comment: Okay I think I understand what you're saying. 
Is the key difference between the two lines the fact that char name[] is a char* while char name[20] is an array, not a pointer?

Comment: @KacyRaye No, when used in a parameter list, an array type `T[N]` is functionally-equivalent to `T*`. That's not to say that they are equivalent in general. When using `T[N]` in, say, the main function, it represents an array, and `T*` represents a pointer to `T`.

Comment: @KacyRaye Are you still having trouble understanding? I can explain further if you want me to! :-)

Comment: Let me read through this one more time and I'll let you know.

Comment: @0x499602D2 After rereading your answer thoroughly, I feel like everything totally makes sense so thank you because I've been stuck on this concept for a while.
I do have one question though.  In the 2nd line that does compile, is the variable name considered a pointer?  Since "Kacy" is a constant char pointer, does name point to the same memory address as  the constant char pointer?

Comment: @KacyRaye No, `name` is an array. There is a difference between pointers and arrays. There is a great thread going over arrays [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c). Scroll down to "Arrays are not pointers".

Comment: Okay thanks.  I didn't think so.  I just wanted to make sure.
Thank for you helping me get my fundamentals down :)

Answer (score 1):

C++ string literals have type "array of n const char", which decays into `const char *` in your use case.  The implicit conversion to `char *` (that is, discarding the `const`) you're trying is deprecated, so there's a warning.  Change the type in the constructor's signature or make an explicit const-cast.

From the C++ standard:

> An ordinary string literal has type "array of *n* const char" and *static* storage duration

Answer (score 0):

The string

```
"Kacy"
```

is not an array of characters when the compiler produces the code. Instead, it will stash the string "Kacy" somewhere in memory, and produce a pointer to that place. So what you get is a `const char *` pointing at the string "Kacy\0".

If you change your constructor to:

```
 Student(const char *nmae)
```

you can use it both as:

```
 Student stud("Kacy");
```

and as this:

```
 char name[20] = "Kacy"; 
 Student stud2(name);
```

Note here that the compiler will generate code to FILL the array `name` with the characters in `"Kacy"`, which is different from just usinv `"Kacy"` as an argument to the `Student` constructor.

Comment: The string "Kacy" *is* an array. Which is why this works: `const char (&ref)[5] = "Kacy";` -- and this: `const char(*ptr)[5] = &"Kacy";`